Why is findMany not working in my generic Prisma service, and how can I fix it?
I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to implement a generic service to list all entries from any Prisma model in my application. I'm using TypeScript with Prisma, and the idea is to pass a Prisma model dynamically to this service function and have it return the result of the findMany query.
Here's the code I have so far:
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

type PrismaClientMethod = '$on' | '$connect' | '$disconnect' | '$use' | '$executeRaw' | '$executeRawUnsafe' | '$queryRaw' | '$queryRawUnsafe' | '$transaction'
type PrismaModelName = keyof Omit<PrismaClient, PrismaClientMethod>
type PrismaModel = PrismaClient[PrismaModelName]

export const genericPrismaListService = async <T extends PrismaModel>(model: T) => {
  return model.findMany()
}

However, when I try to use this genericPrismaListService, I run into issues where the findMany method doesn't seem to be recognized. I get TypeScript errors suggesting that findMany does not exist on the type T. My understanding is that since I’m passing a model from Prisma, the findMany method should be available on any Prisma model, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.
Am I incorrectly typing the model in the generic function, or is there another issue with how I'm using Prisma models generically in TypeScript? What can I do to ensure that findMany (and other model-specific methods like create, update, etc.) are available on the passed model?
Any help on how I can properly type this function and make findMany work would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

// Define the type for model names
type PrismaModelName = keyof PrismaClient

// Define the type for the model methods
type PrismaModel = PrismaClient[PrismaModelName]

export const genericPrismaListService = async <T extends PrismaModel>(modelName: PrismaModelName) => {
    const prisma = new PrismaClient()
    // Access the model dynamically
    const model = prisma[modelName] as T
    // Call findMany on the model
    return model.findMany()
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
